# Evaluating 0xfb-0xfa

Tags: binary, hex

```
0xfb-0xfa
```

I have first turn to binary

```
0xfb=11111011

0xfa=11111010

-0xfa=00000101+1=00000110
```

Now `11111011+00000110=100000001` which is underflow, but it surely incorrect, where did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear whether the initial numbers are signed or unsigned. The results will be identical, but the reasoning is slightly different.

Assuming your initial numbers are unsigned, the initial conversion is incorrect.
Your data are 8 bits when coded in binary as unsigned. 
If you want to convert them to 2s complement without truncation, you need an extra bit. So

```
+0xfb = 0 11111011
+0xfa = 0 11111010
-0xfa = 1 00000110
```

Now we can compute the addition

```
        (1)
  0xfb     0 11111011
 -0xfa   + 1 00000110
           ----------
           0 00000001
```

We can notice that there is no overflow. There is a carry out, but we can just ignore it in 2s complement. And the sum of a positive and negative number cannot overflow.

Now, as the two MSB are equal, result can be shortened to 8 bits giving the obvious result of 1.

If initial numbers are signed, most your computation is correct. All the operations can be done on 8 bits. And the result will be on 8 bits.

```
        (1)
  0xfb     11111011
 -0xfa   + 00000110
           ----------
           00000001
```

There is a carry out, but no over or underflow. The result is correct.

Comment: So in 2s complement there will never be overflow? we ignore the the carry out?

Comment: Overflow is complex to determine for 2s complement. There is never overflow if operands are of != sign and there may or not be a carry out (that can be ignored). If operands are both >=0, so must be the result and no carry out should happen. If operands are both <0, result must be <0 and there must be a carry out. A global rule is that carry-out==carry-in-at-MSB, otherwise there is an overflow. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805087/how-is-overflow-detected-in-twos-complement